# How would I get a button to change stylesheets, be saved to local storage, and appear on all pages of a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm currently very new to code and understand very little terminology and I'm kinda scared to ask for help but here it goes.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:
I'm currently trying to create a website with multiple pages. One of the pages I want to be reserved for Settings where you can change the theme of all the pages to night or day mode. I have one button on the page and when you click it I'd like the entire website (every page) to go into "Night mode" by reading a dark mode css I made. If night mode is disabled I'd like it to be in day mode by reading a day mode css I also have made. I'd also like to save your preference as a cookie in local storage so if a user returns to the website it is still in the mode the user left the website in.

I'm unsure if this is all possible but it would be amazing if anyone could help me figure it out as I feel as though I have almost got it to work but have been stuck for ages! I'll add my html, javascript, and both css files so you can kind of see what I have made so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">

</head>
<body class="pagestyle">

    <center>

    <h1>Veracity</h1>
    <h2>Settings</h2>

    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="Veracity.html">Home</a>
        <a href="Articles.html">Articles</a>
        <a href="News.html">News</a>
        <a href="Pictures.html">Pictures</a>
        <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="NMTP.html">Settings</a>
    </div>

    <button id="change-theme-btn">Night Mode</button>

    <script src="night-mode.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Next is the Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("change-theme-btn").addEventListener("click", 
function () {
let darkThemeEnabled = document.body.classList.toggle("pagestyle");
window.localStorage.setItem("pagestyle-enabled", darkThemeEnabled)
});

if (JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("pagestyle-enabled"))) {
    document.body.classList.add("pagestyle");
}
```

Finally, Here is my day time/default css file:

```
#lightSwitchOff{ display:inline; }
#lightSwitchOn{ display:none; }

#span{
    font-family:Times New Roman;
    color: black;
    font-size: 25px;
}

body {
    background-color: white;

}

button {
    background-color: teal;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family:Cooper Black;
}

h1 { 
    color:teal;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family:Magneto;

}

h2 {
    color:black;
    font-family:Magneto;

}

p {
    color:teal;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Courier New;

}

.div{
    border:10px solid teal;
    width:200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:20px;
    padding:10px;

}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #a0a0a0;
    font-family: Cooper Black;
}

.navbar a {
    float: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: teal;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: white;

}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

And here's the night mode css file:

```
#lightSwitchOff{ display:none; }
#lightSwitchOn{ display:inline; }

#span{
    font-family:Times New Roman;
    color: #30d110;
    font-size: 25px;
}

body {
    background-color: black;

}

button {
    background-color: #30d110;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family:Cooper Black;
}

h1 {
    color:#30d110;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family:Magneto;
}

h2 {
    color:white;
    font-family:Magneto;

}

p {
    color:#30d110;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Courier New;
}

body {
    background-color: black;

}

.div{
    border:10px solid #30d110;
    width:200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:20px;
    padding:10px;

}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #a0a0a0;
    font-family: Cooper Black;
}

.navbar a {
    float: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #30d110;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: white;

}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

I dunno if I've posted too much of my code or too little but like I said I'm new and would like to provide as much information as possible. I think I'm really close but I cannot for the life of me figure out a way to have the css file switch with a single button and have the switch happen across all of my pages on my website. Any advice is appreciated and if I have left out any thing else that would help lead to an answer let me know and I can try to help out! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the css files are separate, then it sounds like you should want your Javascript to dynamically link the proper CSS file at runtime. You should keep your state in your Javascript alone if possible, and not depend on the HTML for it:

```
// defaults to false when LS not populated
let darkEnabled = Boolean(localStorage.darkEnabled);
const cssElem = document.querySelector('link[rel="stylesheet"]');
if (!darkEnabled) cssElem.href = 'default.css';
else cssElem.href = 'darktheme.css';
document.getElementById("change-theme-btn")
  .addEventListener('click', function () {
    darkEnabled = !darkEnabled;
    localStorage.darkEnabled = darkEnabled;
    if (!darkEnabled) cssElem.href = 'default.css';
    else cssElem.href = 'darktheme.css';
  });
```

(assuming you name the dark CSS file `darktheme.css`)

Comment: This helped so much! It got my button to switch between both of my stylesheets! Do you know if there is anything I could add to it to make the stylesheet save if the page is refreshed?

Comment: Just add the test to the beginning of the code as well - see edit

Comment: I added it to the beginning and it didn't seem to work... my console displayed the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: cssElem is not defined"

Comment: Just add the cssElem assignment above the test

Comment: When I added it above the test and I refreshed the webpage the night mode did save but the default mode refreshes to the night mode css. Do you know any thing that could be making that happen?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem i would approach setting cookies.

Lets assume that your user has selected "night mode" then you can set a cookie with the new styelsheet and you can check if that new cookie exists on every page, if the cookie exists then you can replace your existing style.css with the new nightmode.css file

**setting the cookie**

```
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

    setCookie('stylesheet', 'main.css', 365);
```

**Getting the cookie**

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

// if cookie exists then change the css file
console.log(getCookie('stylesheet'));
```